# POST request with Multipart File and parameters in Java

Tags: java, spring, http, post, httpurlconnection

I have `POST API endpoint` in **Java** , which is like below which is to be called for `storing student marksheet` in the portal.

**`POST API endpoint`**

```
/**
@param name
        Name of student
@param class
        Class of student
@param section
        Section of student
@param rollno
        Roll Number of student
@param file
        Marksheet of student in .xlsx format
**/
@PostMapping(value="/storeMarksheet", produces = "application/json")
public String performTaskAndSendResponse(
    @RequestParam String name,
    @RequestParam String class,
    @RequestParam String section,
    @RequestParam String rollno,
    @RequestPart(name=file) @ApiParam(".xlsx file") MultipartFile file
){
    System.out.println("Inside store marksheet endpoint") // not getting printed
    // Store marksheet and return response accordingly
}
```

And have written a function like below to call it

**`POST API function call`**

```
public String postAPI(String name, String class, String section, String rollno, MultipartFile marksheet){
    Map<String, Object> student = new HashMap<String, Object>;
    student.put("name", name);
    student.put("class", class);
    student.put("section", section);
    student.put("rollno", rollno);
    student.put("file", marksheet);

    String dataAsString = student.toString();
    String API = "https://somedomain.com/example/storeMarksheet";
    StringBuilder resp = new StringBuilder();
    String lineResponse = null;

    try{
        URL url = new URL(API);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Using HttpURL connection
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.write(dataAsString.getBytes("utf-8"));
        
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));
        while((lineResponse = br.readLine()) != null) resp.append(lineResponse.trim());

        System.out.println(resp.toString());
        return resp;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }

}
```

However seems like the call is **`not going`** at all.
Using *HttpURLConnection* for making http calls.

**`NOTE`**

1. First priority is sending via `HttpURLConnection` only, if impossible
   then open to other solutions
2. The above POST API endpoint is working perfectly in swagger.

Comment: What makes you think that `student.toString` will be the proper way to send the data as a request body? It isn't. I would also strongly suggest to use something else (like `RestTemplate` or `WebClient` to send a request as you are already using Spring).

Comment: Can you please post an answer.... i am open to stuff, it is just that i have done mostly using string that is why thinking it was possible this way. Please help

Comment: Can anyone help on this? I am trying and in need for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Tried to do via HttpURLConnection but nothing worked for me. Therefore posting answer using another process

```
public String postAPI(String name, String class, String section, String rollno, MultipartFile marksheet){
    String responseStr = null;
    try{
        HttpPost req = new HttpPost("https://somedomain.com/example/storeMarksheet");
        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        builder.addTextBody("name",name);
        builder.addTextBody("class",class);
        builder.addTextBody("section",section);
        builder.addTextBody("rollno",rollno);
        builder.addbinaryBody("file", marksheet.getBytes(), ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, marksheet.getOriginalFilename() );
    
        HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
        req.setEntity(entity);
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        CloseableHttpResponse res = client.execute(req);
        responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEnity().toString());
        System.out.println(responseStr); 
        return responseStr;
    }catch(Exception e){
        //do something.. have put common exception for now
        return null;
    }finally{
        try{
            res.close();
            client.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //do something.. have put common exception for now
        }
        
    }
}
```